# How to pivot a dynamic row values to dynamic column names?

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have 4 tables where I get my resultset and pivot the rows from these to columns.

For the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `categoryId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKjnsw2k93ncjrapn5kqlakucbi` (`categoryId`),
  KEY `FKp154cf9pr3p8l0mta4bfc78w6` (`itemInventoryId`),
  KEY `FKaqi29x32v3eso66pdum47woa6` (`itemTypeId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKaqi29x32v3eso66pdum47woa6` FOREIGN KEY (`itemTypeId`) REFERENCES `itemtype` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKjnsw2k93ncjrapn5kqlakucbi` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryId`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKp154cf9pr3p8l0mta4bfc78w6` FOREIGN KEY (`itemInventoryId`) REFERENCES `iteminventory` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `orderdetails` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orderAmt` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orderQty` double NOT NULL,
  `unitPrice` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orderId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKitt7j8imhq4iv95p8p7hwx32g` (`itemId`),
  KEY `FKs7i5eyowhf8cl163vl9u3gjuj` (`orderId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKitt7j8imhq4iv95p8p7hwx32g` FOREIGN KEY (`itemId`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKs7i5eyowhf8cl163vl9u3gjuj` FOREIGN KEY (`orderId`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grossTotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `netTotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orderCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Here is the sample data set:

```
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (1,'Beef'),(2,'Pork'),(3,'Fruits');

INSERT INTO `item` VALUES (1,'Liempo #231',3),(3,'Indian Mango',3);

INSERT INTO `orderdetails` VALUES (1,300.00,3,100.00,2,1),(2,720.00,1,720.00,3,1),(3,2163.00,3,721.00,2,2),(4,800.00,1,800.00,3,2);

INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (1,1020.00,687.00,'2006-0001',2),(2,12863.00,13093.00,'2006-0002');
```

Currently, I have this MySQL query

```
SELECT 
    item.name,
    category.name,
    SUM(orderdetails.orderQty) as TOTALORDERS,
    SUM(orderdetails.orderAmt) as TOTALAMOUNT
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN orderdetails ON orderdetails.orderId= orders.id
INNER JOIN item ON item.id = orderdetails.itemId
GROUP BY item.name;
```

The only issue I have now is making the row values of orderCode into column names and it's been days I've been trying out things but I can't find a solution. What I need is something like below:

```
name  |    category   | TOTALORDERS  | TOTALAMOUNT | 2006-0001  | 2006-0002
Item1 |     cat1      |      5       |     500     |     200    |    300
Item2 |     cat2      |      200     |      4      |      2     |     2
```

Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: *I want it to be included in the names of the columns* Only dynamic SQL (prepared statement) may solve. *like WEDNESDAY 2020-06-24* This needs to restrict the source data with one week (you must exclude the case when 2 Wednesday data, for example, 2020-06-17 and 2020-06-24, is included into).

Comment: @Akina the thing is, if I exclude the case on Wednesday, for example, I get an SQL syntax error and asks me to add the ORDERDATE on the GROUP BY function. If I do so, the columns become "ORDERDATE" instead and the values or the date values will be in row output :/

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, it was my first time asking for an SQL-related question and didn't realize I wasn't able to add the create db and tables code :/

Comment: Hello @Strawberry I've updated my question.

Comment: Much better. But, as mentioned, I'd handle this kind of thing in application code

Comment: And note that in general, non-aggregated columns in the SELECT clause must also be included in the GROUP BY

Comment: @Strawberry I would've done in it application code too but ryt now, I'm afraid I'm not allowed to. :/